# extract css urls using preg_math

Tags: php, regex

I use this function for get url list from css text. It success but if css text contains base64 image urls it break all. It should pass base64 image urls. How can i fix it?

```
function extractCssUrls( $text )
    {
        $urls=array();
        $matches=array();
        //$url_pattern     = '(([^\\\\\'", \(\)]*(\\\\.)?)+)';
        $url_pattern     = '(([^\\\\\'"\(\)]*(\\\\.)?)+)'; 
        $urlfunc_pattern = 'url\(\s*[\'"]?' . $url_pattern . '[\'"]?\s*\)';
        $pattern         = '/(' .
            '(@import\s*[\'"]' . $url_pattern     . '[\'"])' .
            '|(@import\s*'      . $urlfunc_pattern . ')'      .
            '|('                . $urlfunc_pattern . ')'      .  ')/iu';
        if ( !preg_match_all( $pattern, $text, $matches ) )
            return $urls;

        // @import '...'
        // @import "..."
        foreach ( $matches[3] as $match )
            if ( !empty($match) )
                $urls['import'][] =
                    preg_replace( '/\\\\(.)/u', '\\1', $match );

        // @import url(...)
        // @import url('...')
        // @import url("...")
        foreach ( $matches[7] as $match )
            if ( !empty($match) )
                $urls['import'][] =
                    preg_replace( '/\\\\(.)/u', '\\1', $match );

        // url(...)
        // url('...')
        // url("...")
        foreach ( $matches[11] as $match )
            if ( !empty($match) )
                $urls['property'][] =
                    preg_replace( '/\\\\(.)/u', '\\1', $match );

        $urls=(isset($urls['property']))?$urls['property']:array();

        $urls=array_unique($urls);
        $urls=array_values($urls);

        return $urls;
    }
```

I found the bug. I remove `,` char from `$url_pattern` from variable.
 `$url_pattern='(([^\\\\\'"\(\)]*(\\\\.)?)+)';`

Comment: Can you explain how you got to `(([^\\\\\'", \(\)]*(\\\\.)?)+)` for `$url_pattern`? That doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: A CSS parser might be more appropriate for this task.

Comment: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/01/php_tip_how_extract_urls_css_file#UsingreturnedURLs

Comment: Regular expressions are not meant for attempting to "parse" nested structures, like HTML, CSS, and the like. However if you're looking at a single file you could get some consistency, but if what you're doing isn't for a single file, you're better off looking for or implementing a parser.